# Json data is correctly being fetched but bootstrap typeahead is not poping the data?

Tags: jquery, json, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using json to get the data.Data is fetched up ,alerts and then nothing happenns in typehead inputbox.

Here is the php code

> sq=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM  wp_posts where post_type='post' and post_title LIKE '%{$q}%'"));
>
> $array=array();
>
> foreach($sq as $fsq) {
>
> $array[]=array( "id" => "$fsq->ID", "text" => "$fsq->post_title" );
>
> }
>
> echo json_encode($array);

Here goes the Jquery

```
                            jQuery('.searchh').typeahead({


                            source: function (query, process) {

                                jQuery.ajax({
                                    url: 'wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/field2.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'JSON',


                                    data: 'query=' + query,
                                    success: function (data) {


                                        jQuery.each(data, function (index, data) {
                                            console.log(data['text']);

                                            process(data['text']);

                                        });


                                    }


                            },
                            minLength: 1,
                            items: 9999,
                            onselect: function (obj) { console.log(obj) }




                        })
```

Data is correctly being pulled.that means json is working correctly.The only conflict is with the typeahead code.once the data is pulled up,nothing happends,not even error is shown in console log.

I have much wasted my time on it.Plz help.

Comment: Please take a look in this line of code jQuery.each(data, function (index, data) { } instead of data use value or some other variable. and then use console.log(value['text']);

Comment: @S.Russell  i replaced the data word with response.But still not working.

Comment: Can you please use console.log(value.text);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't return anything from the AJAX `success`. Try this:

```
jQuery('.searchh').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/field2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            success: function (resp) {
                var items = [];
                jQuery.each(resp, function (index, item) {
                    items.push(item['text']);
                });
                console.log(items);
                return process(items);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    items: 9999,
    onselect: function (obj) { 
        console.log(obj) 
    }
});
```

Remember, the `console` is your friend.

Hope it helps!